# How to deep copy XDocument / XElement preserving Line Info

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, system.xml

I have an XDocument loaded with LoadOptions.SetLineInfo.  I need to take a copy of this object, preserving the line info.

Unfortunately, the copy constructors seem to lose the line info - as does a ToString / Parse.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating new XDocument from the old one. Somthing like this.

```
XDocument original = ....
using(var reader = original.CreateReader())
{
    var copy = XDocument.Load(reader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
}
```

This should do the trick.